# How to write sql query using a table that references same field twice

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following sqlite schema:

```
sqlite> .schema

CREATE TABLE widgets
(
     id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, 
     pnum varchar(10), 
     destvarchar(100), 
     class varchar(10), 
     name varchar(255), 
     grp integer
);

CREATE TABLE widget_grps
(
     id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT, 
     group_id integer, 
     member_id integer, 

     FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES widgets(id), 
     FOREIGN KEY (member_id) REFERENCES widgets(id)
);
```

Data in my widget_grps looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from widget_grps limit 2;
35|2103|304
36|2103|305
sqlite>
```

And in widgets:

```
sqlite> select * from widgets where id=2103;
2103|90042|Group||Widget Group 1|1
sqlite> select * from widgets where id=304;
304|11681|dest1222|smfass|Johnn Doe|0
sqlite>
```

So as you can see the group_id and member_id fields both point to the widgets table, but to different values.  I'm trying to write a query that will return data like this:

```
   group_pnum  | group_id   |widget_pnum  | widget_id
   =======================================|===============
   90042       | 2103       | 11681       |  304
```

Can you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT 1**

```
sqlite> select * from widget_grps where group_id is null or group_id ='';
sqlite> select * from widget_grps where member_id is null or member_id='';
sqlite>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
sqlite>SELECT count(*) FROM (
   ...>SELECT wg.pnum as group_pnum, g.group_id, ww.pnum as member_pnum,      
   ...>g.member_id
   ...>from widget_grps g
   ...>  join widgets wg on g.group_id = wg.id
   ...>  join widgets ww on g.member_id = ww.id
   ...>)

 2547
 sqlite>


sqlite> select count(*) from widget_grps;
4110
sqlite>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the following query should yield the desired results:

```
select wg.pnum as group_pnum, g.group_id, ww.pnum as widget_pnum, g.member_id
from widget_grps g
     left join widgets wg on g.group_id = wg.id
     left join widgets ww on g.member_id = ww.id
```

If you want to select only items where `group_id` and `member_id` are different in `widget_grps`, then add a condition like:

```
where g.group_id <> g.member_id
```

Comment: @JNevill: thanks. Focused too much on the result's column names :-)

Comment: hm.  when i wrap that query with a select count(*) from ...  the record count that comes back is way less than select count(*) from widget_grps

Comment: @dot: do you have `NULL` values in `group_id` or `member_id`?

Comment: hm. cannot explain actually unless referential integrity were violated (which cannot be the case due to the `references`-clauses. Anyway, can you try it out with left joins?

Comment: I also thought of duplicate `group_id x member_id`-pairs in `widget_grps`, but these would also yield duplicates in the result of the join. You did't use any `distinct`, did you?

Comment: And can you please post both `count(*)`-queries together with their result values?

Comment: confusing; and with the left joins?

Comment: Stephan it was the "left join" vs. "join" .  I should have tried that.  My bad.  Thanks so much!!